# Wordpress Customizer Image show only a number

Tags: wordpress

I have written the following code for an image:

```
function wp_mytheme_register_images_start($wp_customize){
    // Section
    $wp_customize->add_section('sec_start_images', array(
            'title' => 'Startseite-Bilder',
            'description' => 'Reihenfolge der Bilder für die Startseite',
        )
    );
    // Settings
    $wp_customize->add_setting('set_start_images_3', array(
        //'type' => 'theme_mod',
        'default' => '',
        // 'capability' => 'edit_theme_options',
        'sanitize_callback' => 'absint',
        'transport'      => 'refresh',
                'height'        => 310
    ));
    // Controls
    $wp_customize->add_control( new WP_Customize_Cropped_Image_Control( $wp_customize, 'ctrl_start_image_3', array(
        'label'             => __(‚Image‘ #1, 'wp_my’theme),
        'section'           => 'sec_start_images',
        'settings'          => 'set_start_images_3',
        'flex_width'        =>  false,
        'flex_height'       => false,
        'width'             => 1920,
        'height'            => 310
    )));
}
add_action('customize_register', 'wp_mytheme_register_images_start');
```

I have embedded the following code on my site:

```
<section class="section-bottom-banner">
    <img src="<?php echo esc_url(get_theme_mod('set_start_images_3')); ?>" alt="">
</section>
```

As output I get only one number (http://280).

What am I doing wrong??

Tx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To Get an image via Customizer's Cropped Image control, you will need to use wp_get_attachment_image_src() as it returns the attachment id, as shown:

```
$image_url = wp_get_attachment_image_src(get_theme_mod('set_start_images_3'));
<section class="section-bottom-banner">
    <img src="<?php echo esc_url($image_url[0]); ?>" alt="">
</section>
```

Answer (score 1):

The return value from the get_theme_mod is an image id. you can use wp_get_attachment_image to get the image html. https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_get_attachment_image/

```
<section class="section-bottom-banner">
    <?php echo wp_get_attachment_image( get_theme_mod('set_start_images_3'), 'thumbnail'); ?>
</section>
```